# How to use functors in javascript

Tags: javascript

Given a function that takes a type `a`, I need to apply function `z` that returns a function that takes type `b`. Basically:

```
z -> f(a) -> f(b)
```

Here is a more specific example. This is a function that takes a string and returns a set of methods that use the string:

```
# f(a)
_typeCheck = (str) ->
    isArray: -> str is TYPES.ARRAY
```

I want to transform this function into:

```
# f(b)
_typeCheck = ->
    isArray: (str) -> str is TYPES.ARRAY
```

What is the function `z` that will do this? Please help.

**NOTE**

I'm trying to use a functional programming concept here. Haskell has functors that modify type constructors to take in different types. I believe a similar concept would help me solve my problem. Read more [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#the-functor-typeclass)

Comment: "Functor"s? I bet you came from a C++ background.

Comment: nope, far from it. Haskell.

Comment: So, can you clear up what your types are? JavaScript is loosely typed, so this could get tricky very fast.

Comment: Here is a great article on what you are trying to do: http://functionaljavascript.blogspot.com/2013/07/functors.html

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is having a function that takes a "type". JavaScript is loosely typed so any type enforcement [will need to come from you](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

That said, you can define a function that returns another function like this:

```
function factory(a) {
    // check typeof a
    return function(b) {
        // do something with a
        // check typeof b
    };
}

// invoke
var myNewFunction = factory("a string");
myNewFunction("another string");
```

If you are looking for a function that returns a map of functions for checking types perhaps you could use a pattern like this:

```
function _typeCheck() {
    return {
        isArray: function(o) {
            return Array.isArray(o);
        },
        isString: function(o) {
            return typeof o === 'string';
        },
        ...etc
    };
}
console.log(_typeCheck().isArray(['one','two']));
console.log(_typeCheck().isString('foo'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Haskell, but in JS you can construct something like this:

```js
// define some functors

list = xs => a2b => xs.map(a2b);

tree = t => a2b =>
    t ? {
        x: a2b(t.x),
        le: tree(t.le)(a2b),
        ri: tree(t.ri)(a2b)
    }
        : null;

maybe = x => a2b => x ? a2b(x) : x;


// add five to any functor

add5 = f => f(x => x + 5);

// let's test

myTree = {
    x: 1,
    le: {
        x: 2,
        le: {x: 3},
        ri: {x: 4}
    },
    ri: {x: 4}
};

myList = [10, 11, 12, 13];

log = x => document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(x, 0, 3) + "</pre>");

log([
  add5(maybe(22)),
  add5(maybe(undefined)),
  add5(list(myList)),
  add5(tree(myTree))
]);
```